# Web Service in SQL server (Alternative solution)

Tags: sql-server, web-services, web, database-administration

HI All Currently we have a web service in the Our Platform, that is called from the database.

When something changes inside the database, it should by itself initiate and inform an External Application. 
The application should NOT be polling the database and enquiring of the change.

The current solution which we have is a HTTP call but this has it's own overhead. Also, it does not guarantee 100% message delivery. 
So is there an alternate solution. 
Can the database write to a Queue?

Comment: What is changing it if not the application? Seems like an xy question to me; the issue isn't how to get SQL Server to "let the application know", but how to stop changes being made outside to application (as it would be aware of itself).

Comment: @Larnu what happen here is if some Table got modify or Updated. The HTTP request we do sometime fail to send request to external application.which lead to a real time issue  on production server.

Comment: You're saying that the table's definition was updated? Why is your application not being updated too then? That's poor DevOps planning; it's neither the database's or Application's fault if the definition of the data has been changed in one environment and not the other. If you are deploying updates to the database, you should also be deploying them to the application. if you're not, you need to look at your deployment processes and fix them.

Comment: @Larnu you didn't get The Point The issue we face is sending the HTTP request from database to external application to get real time data.The Problem when sometime SQL doesn't send response to external Application   whenever any Table data getting added or modify.looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Yes it can send to a queue. SQL Server has it's own built in message queue but unfortunately it can only talk to other SQL Server queues. Are you saying if 1000 rows get updated this system needs to send 1000 HTTP messages? It's not really a common design pattern - to shoot off message from a database change. As already mentioned it seems like an XY question - what are you really trying to do? Anyway, unless you post some code and a specific problem / error message, this will most likely be closed.